# Counting the numbers of rows in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

In PHP you can use the function mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) to check how much rows there are in the result set.

I was wondering, how to do this if you are using Zend Framework. What I'm trying to achieve is to check if the email existst in the database table: customer.

I have this code.

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$query = "SELECT column1,column2 FROM ". Zim_Properties::getTableName('Customer') ." WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
```

I use Zend Framework 1.8

Comment: echo $stmt->count(); ??

Comment: That gives this error "Call to undefined method Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli::count()"

Comment: echo $stmt->rowCount(); !!!

Comment: You have data/records in $stmt ??

Comment: Well, $stmt is an object in Zend Framework. And by calling rowCount() you'll get the numbers of row which were affected.

Comment: ok, so u got the count using rowCount() ?

Comment: Yes, why does this surprise you? Did I miss something?

Comment: no no ... thats gud if problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve the problem was the following.

To know more information about the var `$stmt` I used `Zend_Debug::dump($stmt);`

It showed:

`object(Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli)#14 (12) {`

So I went to the folder `"library/Zend/Db/Statement"`, and opened the file `Mysqli.php`.

Then I checked every method available in the class and noticed that the method `rowCount` was the needed one.

At the Controller I called this rowCount function.

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
$query = "SELECT column1,column2 FROM ". Zim_Properties::getTableName('Customer') ." WHERE email = '".$_POST['email']."'";
$stmt = $db->query($query);
echo $stmt->rowCount();
```